# Daily notification using alarm manager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have written this code that will be executed everyday and display a notification:

```
class DailyNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Register the alarm and set it at 7am everyday (repeating mode)
    public static void registerAlarm(Context paramContext) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 7) {
            calendar.add(7, 1);
        }
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        // PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast
        PendingIntent localPendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getBroadcast(
                        paramContext,
                        22341,
                        new Intent(
                                "com.bestweightmanager.example.exampledailynotification.DAILY_NOTIFICATION"),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Retrieve an AlarmManager to set a repeating daily alarm
        ((AlarmManager) paramContext.getSystemService("alarm")).setRepeating(1,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000,
                localPendingIntent);
    }
}
```

The manifiest file looks like the following:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".utils.DailyNotification"
    android:process=":remote" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.bestweightmanager.example.exampledailynotification.DAILY_NOTIFICATION" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But I don't get any notifications. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?

Also, that what is meaning of below code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 7) {
    calendar.add(7, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering in parts.

## 1.

Replace the line in your code

```
((AlarmManager) paramContext.getSystemService("alarm")).setRepeating(1,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000,
                localPendingIntent);
```

with this line:

```
((AlarmManager) paramContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).setRepeating(1,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                localPendingIntent);
```

You actually need to get system service - `Context.ALARM_SERVICE`

And instead of setting the repeat frequency to 1000 ms, you need to use `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY`, so as to trigger it daily on the desired set time.

## 2.

About the meaning of this code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 7) {
    calendar.add(7, 1);
}
```

Here `calendar.add(7, 1)` does not makes perfect sense to me. The add() function of calendar is used to add a given amount to a specific Calendar field, identified by a unique integer.

If your code line `calendar.add(7, 1);` is replaced with `calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`, than this code might make some sense.
It will than actually check that while registering the alarm, if the current Hour of Day is greater than 7 (i.e, current day time has exceeded 7 AM), than it will set the calendar object (which is later used to register alarm) for 7 AM of next date (tomorrow).

## 3.

Also I am doubtful about the declaration in your manifest file. You need to crosscheck it with the source from where you are referring.

In general, the structure of manifest file for AlarmManager should look somewhat like this:

```
<application>

    <activity>
        <intent-filter>
            <action/>

            <category/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".DailyNotification" />
</application>
```

Hope that helps.